# Email file attachment from command line

Tags: linux, mail-command

I want to email the file returned by the following command as an attachment (on RHEL/CentOS):

```
ls -1 $(hostname -s)*.xml | tail -n 1
```

For example, the command above returns `server-20140430080511.xml` and I want to then email that file to a recipient from the command line, all done in the one command (on one line) so that we can script/automate this process.

Can anyone suggest how to do this on a single line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `uuencode`:

```
uuencode server-20140430080511.xml abcdef | mail recipient@some.host
```

Where `abcdef` is the name the attachment will have in the email (which can of course be the same as the filename to encode, but it needs to be specified).

(On Ubuntu, the `uuencode` command is in `sharutils`, and `mail` e.g. in `mailutils`).